# How can I pass call a function on a child controller from the parent and pass a parameter?

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML page and a parent controller:

```
<a data-ng-click="callChild('x')"></a>

$scope.callChild = function (task) {

}
```

How can I make it so that when the link is clicked then the function callChild is 
executed in a child controller and the argument is passed to the child controller function?

Comment: May i ask, what do you mean by 'child controller'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent controller can notify child controller by using `$broadcast`.

Here is some example <kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/986/)</kbd>:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    
    <a data-ng-click="callChild('x')">Click me</a>
    
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">            
      
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

function ParentCtrl($scope, $timeout) {    
  
     $scope.callChild = function (val) {
       $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', val);
    };
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) { 
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function (event, val) {
        alert('from child ' + val);
    });
}
```

*Reference*

> **$broadcast** -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes,
>
> **$emit** -- dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.